# Neo4j on Heroku with Python

Tags: python-2.7, heroku, neo4j

I'm trying to get the [Neo4j on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/neo4j) and [Getting Started with Python on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python) tutorials up and going. The Neo4j one works fine, but the Python one has problems.

> For anyone else trying to follow this tutorial, I've recorded the
>   problems and my solutions to help you out as well.

This is all done on a Win7 x64 dev machine.

**Q1)** "virtualenv venv --distribute" - errors with:

'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

*A1)* The workaround is to fully qualify the path to:
"C:\Python27\Scripts\virtualenv venv --distribute"

**Q2a)** "foreman start" - errors with:

'foreman' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

*A2)* Looks like a path issue so I ran the line:

"set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\ruby-1.9.2\bin\"

**Q2b)** "foreman start" now errors:

Bad file descriptor
{Ruby paths...}

**A2b) Help?**

So I can't run the app locally, but maybe still on the server, so moving on...

**Q3)** .gitignore - can't create this file on Windows.

*A3)* Clone another project and copy that file and edit.

**Q4)** "git push heroku master" - errors with:

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

**A4)** Apparently need to create new SSH keys. [Managing Your SSH Keys](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys) Note again fully quality the path such as below and select the new key to add to heroku.

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh-keygen.exe" -t rsa"

**Q5)** Try "git push heroku master" the same with the Neo4j test app "flask-py2neo" - errors during the compile. Is this example current?

*A5)* Remove distribute from requirements.txt.

Any ideas?

Comment: The question 2B still is outstanding if anyone has an answer?